# TabHostのsetOnClickListenerの表記の仕方を教えて下さい。

Tags: android, android-fragments

TabHostのsetOnClickListenerの表記の仕方を教えて下さい。

詳細：
　お世話なっております。

下記の質問から派生した質問です。
　「現在、「開いているタブボタン」を押した際に、設定しているWebViewの再読込（Top画面）を読み込むにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか？」

下記のコードで目的の動きが可能になったのですが、コードが長くなるため他の短くなる書き方について勉強しております。

```
//tab0　再クリック時に表示画面を戻す
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab0　クリック");
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);//一度、tab1を表示させ（なんちゃって初期化？）すぐに下を表示させる)
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);//これでtab0が表示される
    }
});
//tab1　再クリック時に表示画面を戻す
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab1　クリック");
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);//一度、tab0を表示させ（なんちゃって初期化？）すぐに下を表示させる)
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);//これでtab1が表示される
    }
        });
```

例えば、以下のようにしたいのですが、onClick内の「i」の処理に困っているところです。
アドバイスを頂ければ幸いです。

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {       
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if( i == 0){//ここがエラー
                Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab0をクリック");
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
            }else{
                Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab0以外をクリック");
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            }
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(i);//ここがエラー
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

変数`i`を渡すとエラーとなるのは、匿名内部クラスに非finalなローカル変数を渡せないJavaの制約によるものです。

一度finalなローカルな変数を作って渡せば良いように思います。

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(j == 0){
                Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab0をクリック");
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
            }else{
                Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab0以外をクリック");
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            }
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(j);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: quesera2様、ありがとうございます。
無事、動作させることができました。
自分もAndroidStudioの自動修正で「final」にすれば動きそうまでは理解していたのですが、「Javaの制約」と考えがいたっておりませんでした。
また、final int j = i;の部分も気が回りませんでした。
自分のコードではないので、変数を増やさないことばかり考えたのが原因です。
勉強になりました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)`で取得できるViewの`Tag`に、自分の位置を教える方法はどうでしょうか？

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {       
    View tab = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
    tab.setTag(i); // 位置を教える
    tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = (int)v.getTag();
            if(position == 0) { 
                Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab0をクリック");
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
            } else {
                Log.e("mTabHost.getTabWidget()", "tab0以外をクリック");
                mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            }
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `mTabHost.setCurrentTab((int)v.getTag());`へ変えないと動かない気がします。

Comment: 変数`i`には`v.getTag()`の結果が入っているので実は同じなんですが、そもそも外側の変数名を隠すようなコードでわかりにくいので書き直してみました

Comment: fkm様、お世話になっております。
　上記のコードを私の環境で試したところ、以下の部分でエラーが出てしまいました。
int position = (int)v.getTag();
今回は、コード修正作業の時間が決まっていたため、quesera2様のコードを使わしていただきました。
こちらは別課題として勉強して見ようと思います。
ありがとうございました。